# How to visualise SQL from Hibernate HQL (oracle)?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, orm, hql

I have a complex database request  made from some (historical) code using Hibernate towards Oracle 11, as a Named Query expressed in Hibernate Query Language aka HQL.  This request is rather slow and I would like to get it fixed. But since Hibernate HQL operates with objects, it is problematic to understand how that is translated to SQL.

What would be the way to see actual SQL queries that are made for a given Named Query, using any feasible way (code/some software etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please locate file 'hibernate.cfg.xml'. Then, try to locate/add property 'show_sql' and set it as 'true':

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

That should log your queries (without parameters).

Comment: Thank you, could you please amend the answer regarding as to where I can find these logs?

Comment: that depends on your logging configuration, eg. log4j.xml if you are using log4j

Comment: You are welcome. I agree with Bajal, it depends on your logging configuration.